# Ajax effect in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a way to show a GIF image when a ajax call is in process and I hope the image hide when the ajax response is back. Can anyone please help me to do that?
I am not experienced with JQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following method in my own web application.

Give your image an identifier, (eg: `id="loading"`).
Then put the following into a pair of `<script>` tags at the end of your document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading')
        .ajaxStart(function(){$(this).show();})
        .ajaxStop(function(){$(this).hide();})
        .hide()
    ;
});
```

This will add an event handler for every Ajax call, and also hide the image at the end of the initial root page load (assuming it was showing when the page was loading).

I recommend reading through the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) - the knowledge you gain from the first few pages will give you good insight into how jQuery works and will make throwing together dynamic interfaces much easier, everyone has to start somewhere.